# Variable not exporting in order

Tags: powershell

```
$filename = 'c:\reports\mx-facebook.csv'

$MXRecord = Resolve-DnsName 'facebook.com' -Type mx -Server '8.8.8.8' -ErrorAction Stop

$MXRecord | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = "Name"},@{Expression = "Type"},@{Expression = "TTL"},@{Expression = "Section"},@{Expression = "NameExchange"} | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation
```

I have tried exporting many different ways but as show above the output comes out of order like the following. I have done it without the calculated property as well and it still comes out of order.

```
"QueryType","Exchange","NameExchange","Preference","Name","Type","CharacterSet","Section","DataLength","TTL"
"MX","smtpin.vvv.facebook.com","smtpin.vvv.facebook.com","10","facebook.com","MX","Unicode","Answer","64","1563"
```

How can I export it in order like the following.

```
Name                                     Type   TTL   Section    NameExchange
----                                     ----   ---   -------    ------------
facebook.com                             MX     1563  Answer     smtpin.vvv.facebook.com
```

Comment: It's not that it is coming out of order, it just means that the returned object has more properties than you can see by default (on the console) however `Export-Csv` will see them and export them all unless you filter the desired properties before exporting. `$MXRecord[0] | Select-Object *` for a better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the desired properties with `Select-Object` or make your own objects with `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator

```
$MXRecord | Select-Object Name,Type,TTL,Section,NameExchange| Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation
```

or

```
$MXRecord | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name         = $_.name
        Type         = $_.type
        TTL          = $_.ttl
        Section      = $_.section
        NameExchange = $_.nameexchange
    }
} | Export-Csv $filename -NoTypeInformation
```